# How to split a string that is a full path, into its directories?

Tags: path, string-manipulation

Say I have a string for the full path of a directory

```
let myPath = '/go/src/github.com/MyDomain/MyProject'
```

I would like to have an array like

```
['go', 'src', 'github.com', 'MyDomain', 'MyProject']
```

What is the best way of doing that ? I would prefer to make this platform agnostic. So if there is a `split()` function tailored for paths, I would prefer that.

Otherwise I think

```
let out = split(myPath, '/')
```

Should do the trick ?

Comment: Be aware of the UNC pathes (`\\server\share\path\to\file`) on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular `split` function with regex covering 2 path separators.

Windows can use `/` or `\`, plus mix of both:

```
echo split('/go/src/github.com/MyDomain/MyProject', '[/\\]')
echo split('C:\go/src/github.com/MyDomain/MyProject', '[/\\]')
```